# Proper way to handle filenotfoundexception Java

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to find the proper method to handle a fileNotFoundException in the event it occurs in my code.  I currently catch and rethrow the exception but am not sure if this is the most optimal way.  I would like my function to stop running in the event the file cannot be found, which currently does not happen.  What is the typical way of achieving this?

Any tips/insights would be great, thanks in advance.

```
        BufferedReader br = null;
        List<String> names = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/files/names.csv"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            try {
                throw e;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you re-throw the `FileNotFoundException` you immediately re-catch it.  Eliminate the inner `try`/`catch`.  Print the stack trace first, then re-throw.  Or here's an idea: don't catch the exception in the first place.

Comment: This is like asking how to handle being dumped by your significant other. ;-) You are in charge. You need to decide what should happen when your program tries to open the file, and it's not found. Examples include "exit with an error message", "show an error message and allow the user to either pick a different file name or exit", etc., etc. When you know what's required or what you want, _then_ write code to make that happen. If you can't figure that out, then at least you'll be able to ask a meaningful question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try catch` is usually used to avoid throwing the exception. In your case

```
void foo() throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    List<String> names = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/files/names.csv"));
}
```

does the exact same thing as your example code.

If you want to avoid throwing the exception to the caller use `try catch` and to exit the application call `System.exit(0)`

```
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/files/names.csv"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of handing such errors. Here are a few:

1. Throw a non-checked exception. It will have to be caught by someone else, and since it's unchecked, he might not know about it. Not always the best idea, but useful for some cases:

   ```
   try {
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/files/names.csv"));
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e); 
   }
   ```
2. Delcare your method with `throws FileNotFoundException` so callers will have to handle this case.
3. Simply `return` after catching the exception, or even use `System.exit()` if appropriate.

All three approaches will stop the execution of the current function.